# FragmentTabHost and ViewPager duplicated fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I have problem with fragments. I found out that ViewPager use the different instances of my fragments than my FragmentTabHost.

I didn't find out how to add fragments from FragmentTabHost in ViewPager or vice versa.

How to make them both use the same instances?

Answer (score 0):

I did this on one of my applications. The way I accomplished this was by only populating the fragment if the bundle was valid. And I managed bundle from tabhost and viewpager in my adapter. Check out complete implementation [here](https://intelliabb.com/2015/11/12/using-fragmenttabhost-with-viewpager/)